# Mapbox add marker on click

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I would like to get the longitude and latitude by clicking on the map in Mapbox so i can use it for adding markers. The idea is to click on the map and then a popup appears where you can write the marker title. I am not sure how i get the longitude and latitude information by clicking right now.

I would love if anyone can help me with this!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When clicking event fires up, you can get the coordinates with **e.lngLat** , it gives you an object with two attributes of **lat** and **lng**. something like this :

```
map.on('click', (e) => {
    let coords = e.lngLat;
    let lat = coords.lat;
    let lng = coords.lng;
});
```

Comment: Do you know how i can insert the data from lat and lng into a form in django? I know its possible in the views.py but im not sure how i do it in my template.

Comment: Glad it helped! I have not worked with Django, but I think it should not be that difficult if you have basic knowledge of templates. Also, you might want to consider it as a separate question since it's too general and add some code for that to get close to what you want. Good luck!